# so basically i have to make a maze on mips but the program stops when jump to game function

Tags: assembly, mips, maze

so basically i have to make a maze on mips and i think im almost done, the problem i have is after processing the display, when i jump to the game_loop where every movement is being processed by reading an charachter for example "Z" = up, the program shuts down completely ( dropped of bottom)

```
.data
mazeFilename:   .asciiz "C:\\Users\\noahm\\OneDrive\\Bureau\\computer architecture\\Mips opdracht\\Mips opdracht 2\\input_1.txt"
buffer:         .space 4096
newline:        .asciiz "\n"
wallColor:      .word 0x004286F4    # Kleur gebruikt voor muren (blauw)
passageColor:   .word 0x00000000    # Kleur gebruikt voor doorgangen (zwart)
playerColor:    .word 0x00FFFF00    # Kleur gebruikt voor speler (geel)
exitColor:      .word 0x0000FF00    # Kleur gebruikt voor uitgang (groen)

breedte:        .word 32
hoogte:         .word 16



.text 


main:
  
  
   j read_maze


   
   
   loop_game:
    li $t1,0
    li $t2, 0
    li $t3, 0
   
    
    # lees gebruiker input
    li $v0, 12         # System call voor 1 single character
    syscall
    move $s1, $v0      # input charachter opslaan

    
    #  Move up
    beq $s1, 122, move_up

    #  Move down   
    beq $s1,115, move_down

    # Move left
    beq $s1, 113, move_left

    #  Move right
    beq $s1, 100, move_right

    #  Exit the game
    beq $s1, 120, exit_game
   
    
    # If no valid input, continue the loop
    j loop_game


    move_up:
    addi $a2, $a0, -1
    addi $a3, $a1, 0
    jal positie_speler
    j beweging
    
    move_down:
    addi $a2, $a0, 1
    addi $a3, $a1, 0
    jal positie_speler
    j beweging
    
    move_left:
    addi $a2, $a0, 0
    addi $a3, $a1, -1
    jal positie_speler
    j beweging
    
    move_right:
    addi $a2, $a0, 0
    addi $a3, $a1, 1
    jal positie_speler
    j beweging
    
    beweging:
    li $v0, 32
    la $a0, 60
    syscall  # Wacht voor 60s
    
    
   
    


    exit_game:
    li $v0, 10         # System call for exit
    syscall






    read_maze:

    # Open het bestand
    li $v0, 13          # Syscall voor openen bestand
    la $a0, mazeFilename    # Adres van de bestandsnaam
    li $a1, 0           # 0 voor lezen, 1 voor schrijven
    li $a2, 0           # 0 voor standaardmodus
    syscall
    move $s0, $v0       # Bewaar bestandsdescriptornummer

    # Lees de inhoud van het bestand in het buffer
    li $v0, 14          # Syscall voor lezen bestand
    move $a0, $s0       # Bestandsdescriptornummer
    la $a1, buffer      # Adres van het buffer
    li $a2, 4096        # Maximale grootte om te lezen
    syscall
    
    # Sluit het bestand
    li $v0, 16          # Syscall voor sluiten bestand
    move $a0, $s0       # Bestandsdescriptornummer
    syscall

    # Verwerk de inhoud van het doolhof
    la $t0, buffer       # Adres van het buffer
   
   


   verwerkDoolhof:
    lb $t1, 0($t0)      # Laad het eerste teken van het buffer in $t0
    li $t2, 0           # rijnummer
    li $t3, 0           # kolomnummer
   
    
   
    verwerkRegel:

    # Check for newline character
    beq $t1, 10, isNewline   # ASCII value of newline character
    # Process the current character and apply the color
    beq $t1, 119, isWall        # Compare with ASCII value of 'w'
    beq $t1, 112, isPassage     # Compare with ASCII value of 'p'
    beq $t1, 115, isPlayer      # Compare with ASCII value of 's'
    beq $t1, 117, isExit        # Compare with ASCII value of 'u'

    # Your existing code for processing characters and applying colors

    isNewline:  
    addi $t2, $t2, 1 # Increment row number  
    li $t3, 0  # reset column number
    # Move to the next character in the buffer
    addi $t0, $t0, 1
    # Load the next character from the buffer
    lb $t1, 0($t0)
    
    lw $t7, hoogte # laad hoogte in
    
    beq $t2, $t7 , loop_game # als de hoogte wordt bereikt eindig
    
    # Continue processing the next row
    j verwerkRegel

  
    isWall:
    lw $t5, wallColor # laad blauw
    jal GeheugenAdress
    jal color_pixel
    j eindeTeken
    
    isPassage:
    lw $t5, passageColor # laad zwart
    jal GeheugenAdress
    jal color_pixel
    j eindeTeken


    isPlayer:
    lw $t5, playerColor # laad geel
    move $a0, $t2       # startpositie rijnummer
    move $a1, $t3       # startpositie kolomnummer
    jal GeheugenAdress
    jal color_pixel
    j eindeTeken
    
    
    isExit:
    lw $t5, exitColor # laad groen
    jal GeheugenAdress
    jal color_pixel
    j eindeTeken

    eindeTeken:
    addi $t0, $t0, 1    # Ga naar het volgende teken in het buffer
    addi $t3, $t3, 1    # ga naar volgende kolom
    lb $t1, 0($t0)      # Laad het volgende teken van het buffer in $t0
    j verwerkRegel      # Ga terug naar verwerkRegel
    
    
   GeheugenAdress:   #bereken geheugenadress
   subu $sp, $sp, 8    # Reserveer ruimte op de stack
   sw $t2, 0($sp)     # Sla het rijnummer op de stack op
   sw $t3, 4($sp)     # Sla het kolomnummer op de stack op
   
   # use row major, Formule: Ba + (r * K + c) * EL
   lw $t6, breedte      # Breedte van het scherm (in pixels)
   mul $t2, $t6, $t2    # r * K
   add $t2, $t2, $t3    # r * K + c
   sll $t2, $t2, 2      # Elke pixel is 32 bits, dus vermenigvuldig met 4 om het geheugenadres te krijgen ( * EL) 
   la $t3, 0($gp)        # $gp bevat het basisadres
   add $t2, $t2, $t3    # Ba + (r * K + c) * EL
   
   jr $ra
   
 
   color_pixel:         # kleur de pixel op de gegeven geheugenplaats
   
    sw $t5, 0($t2)  # sla kleur op ( gegeven pixel)
    lw $t2, 0($sp)  # Laad het rijnummer van de stack
    lw $t3, 4($sp)  # Laad het kolomnummer van de stack
    addu $sp, $sp, 8 # Maak de stackruimte vrij
   
    jr $ra
```

i genuinly dont know what is going wrong, im just jumping to another funtion and it doesnt work

Comment: Ok, "it doesn't work" needs to be more specific.  What exactly doesn't happen that you think should happen, and this, at the level of assembly or machine code?

Comment: Try using single step to see the first thing that goes wrong and ask/search about that.

Comment: Your parameter passing is non-standard, which is ok, if you are aware of that and know what you're doing.

Comment: Variable initialization seems lacking but there's code missing here so we can't really analyze further.

Comment: @ErikEidt     beq $t2, $t7 , loop_game # als de hoogte wordt bereikt eindig
this line basically means that all the right colors are processed and basically the max row number (16px) is reached. The maze itself is  showing but when it branches to "loop_game" and i enter an input charachter   (syscall) the program stops. i dont know if it makes sense, english isnt my best language

Comment: @ErikEidt  and to answer your question about variable, how should i approach it instead?

Comment: Try to be specific about where it goes wrong.  It is often helpful to have a C language or other language you know well, so you can compare the assembly program's operation with something you know works.